# Circumvent a hop when tracerouting

Tags: routes, vpn, iptables

I have this very peculiar problem. We have an office in Utah which uses five9 call center software to make calls using VOIP. In order for our reps to make calls their computer need to be able to connect to a five9 server which is in California. We can make calls but they are very poor quality and in most cases we stop being able to hear the customers while they still hear us. But it goes on and off. Clearly some sort of a network latency issue.

After a day of troubleshooting, five9 support was able to identify a problem hop while tracerouting to our office from their Cali server. See screenshot:
http://www.networking-forum.com/download/file.php?id=3147

We, in turn did the same thing from our office using WinMTR. So we tracerouted to the five9 server... see screenshot below.

http://www.networking-forum.com/download/file.php?id=3148

Notice how in both traces, from five9 to us and from us to five9, there are a lot of dropped packets when traffic passes through a Teliasonera's hop (telia.net). That surely explains the poor call quality.

The problem is that neither comcast (our service provider) nor five9 can fix the problem as it's outside of their domains.

Question - what can I do to circumvent that particular route? Can I proxy all traffic coming out of the office through a server in some other state? VPN? Squid? Can I route all outgoing traffic through some random server somewhere?

Any creative solutions appreciated.

P.S. Five9 uses java applets launched from the browser to make calls. I tried setting up a squid server and entering the info as proxy in Java control console, but to no avail.

Comment: Did you try reaching out to the owner of the IP, and seeing if they can tell you why your experiencing latency ? Honestly, if your call support third party team won't support end to end delivery, you may want to consider a different call support group.

Comment: telia is huge. What are the chances of me calling their sales department and telling them they need to fix a router somewhere in California. I actually have almost figured out a VPN solution. Will post it here when it's official.

Comment: So basically the way we circumvented that particular route is we set up a server in San Jose with openvpn running on it. Then connected all PCs to it thus making it our proxy to the world. It fixed the problem beautifully. It's obviously a temporary solution for a few days until we can switch ISPs. But in the meantime we don't have to lose any more money.

Answer (score 0):

You could route all traffic to that goes to that ip network to a VPN service, that avoids the network path.

If you have a firewall in place already you just need to reroute the firewall to the vpn path.